# Independence of angular momentum with respect to origin for rotation about center of mass

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

Why is angular momentum for rotation about the center of mass independent of origin of the coordinate system?

Comment: Because you are calculating it according to a definite origin, i.e. in the center on mass frame!

Answer (score 5):

$$\vec L = \sum_i \vec {r_i} \times \vec{p_i} $$

Now changing coordinates to CM, i.e. $\vec{r_i} \rightarrow \vec{R_{CM}}+\vec{\mathfrak{r}_i}$, where $\vec{\mathfrak{r}_i}$ is the new coordinates of the particle according to the CM frame.

$$\vec{L}=\sum_i \left(\vec{R_{CM}}+\vec{\mathfrak{r}_i} \right)\times \vec{p_i}=\vec{R_{CM}} \times \sum_i \vec{p_i}+\sum_i \vec{\mathfrak{r}_i}\times\vec{p_i}$$

Now the first term is zero, because $\sum_i \vec{p_i}$ is zero in the CM frame; and the latter is just the angular momentum in the CM. Ergo:

$$\vec{L}=\vec{L_{CM}}$$

I think this is what OP meant in the question.

Comment: +1, it would be more readable if you used $r'_{i}$ for the new coordinates.

Comment: @Physikslover I changed my notation, how does it look now?

Comment: Looks nice - very arty ;)